# DataGrip [08001] The connection attempt failed. The connection attempt failed

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I can connect to Postgres via PgAdmin, but I can't connect via DataGrip.

I click on Test Connection button but it fails, error is that;

> [08001] The connection attempt failed. The connection attempt failed.

By the way i'm using vpn but pgAdmin can connecting.

Comment: Do you have any firewall on your machine? What is PG server version you are connecting to? Please check idea.log file from Help -> Show log in... - there could be more verbose error.

Comment: Seems that something is wrong with your server

Comment: thanks all of your advice, yes, i'm using vpn but pgAdmin can connecting

Comment: @MehmetTopçu I meet the same case. My app in my local machine can connect to pg with no problem while DataGrip failed with the same error. If I config my VPN disabling the set as system proxy option, then DataGrip backed to work like a chram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem as below,

The window with the test button has an advanced tab

[image]

I added this code to VM options:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Hello. I have the same issue but this does not solve my problem. Any other insight you might be able to share?

Comment: This is my Error:`DBMS: 
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Driver:  (ver. , JDBC)
Effective version: PostgreSQL (ver. 0.0)
The connection attempt failed.`

Comment: I have still the same connection issue in Datagrip via VPN even if I add the vm parameter. I can use pgAdmin to connect the Postgre via VPN. Very confused!